# Pydantic model copied when passing it to another model

Tags: python, pydantic

Pydantic copies a model when passing it to the constructor of another model. This fails:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Child(BaseModel):
    pass
    
class Parent(BaseModel):
    child: Child
        
child = Child()
parent = Parent(child=child)
assert parent.child is child
# Fails
```

It seems `child` is copied when passing it to the parent's constructor and therefore the identities of `child` and `parent.child` are not the same. I would like to have them to be the same as I need to modify `child`'s attributes later and the changes should be seen in `parent.child`.

How do I make Pydantic not copy the child?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Seems this was [an issue](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/1246) but it was [fixed in a PR](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/pull/2193) by creating a [config option](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/#options) `copy_on_model_validation`. If this option is set to `False` for the child, then the child is not copied in the construction.

This does not copy the child:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Child(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        copy_on_model_validation = False

class Parent(BaseModel):
    child: Child

child = Child()
parent = Parent(child=child)
assert parent.child is child
# Passes
```

Comment: Can anyone explain the choice of (shallow) copy as the default behavior? It seems to go against customary python syntax.